# Get value from html textbox with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC app and would like to do some "stuff" with a value in the textbox before its sent back to the controller.

So I have a textbox in a form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm","Home")
{
    <p>Enter Value<p>
    @Html.TextBox("amount")
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

normally i would use something like this in JS:

```
var value = document.getElementById(ID).value;
```

So how would I do this with the HTML Helpers? is it possible to give this textbox an id?

Comment: You can "alter" the value of the textbox only server side, before it gets sent to the client. There is no way to access it client side, using helpers.

Comment: I dont want to alter the value just get the value and say put it into a javascript variable, is that possible

Comment: If the value is "known" server side, then yes: `var myVar = '@Model.MyVarValue';` (you might have to play with `Html.Raw()`. If the value is written by the user (i.e. after the page gets rendered), you need JavaScript to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get an HTML Helper for that, but this might help you.

```
var value = document.getElementById('@Html.Id("amount")').value;
```

using the `@Html.Id()` Html Helper you will get the id of that specific viewData

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can assign `Id`, `Class` and various `Html` `attributes` to any `Html Helper` as these helpers are parsed to normal `html` tags.

E.g

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.amount,new { id = "txtAmount", class="anyClass" })

or

@Html.TextBox(m=>m.amount,null,new { id = "txtAmount", class="anyClass" })
```

This is parsed to

```
<input id="txtAmount" name="amount" class="anyClass" type="text" />
```

Then in javascript you can access value of this control as

```
  var value = document.getElementById("txtAmount").value;
```

Comment: by adding the id as you have shown its put the { id = "txtAmount" } into the text box?

Comment: check update use `TextBoxFor` or change overload for `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

we can specify additional html attributes when using html helpers in mvc

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049(v=vs.118).aspx

The html attributes are specified as simple object 
eg

```
new { id = "text1", maxlength="20", size="15" }
```

Method Signature

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    Object value,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```